# Bloquear indexação por robots em controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, seo

Estou fazendo uso do CodeIgniter 2 para montar um site.
A área de administração fica na url `http://meudominio.com/mod`, para acessar precisa passar por login.
Para evitar a indexação dos motores de busca, configurei o arquivo routes

```
$route['mod/(:any)'] = "$1";
$route['mod_upload'] = '';
$route['mod_config'] = '';
$route['mod_logo_upload'] = '';
```

O acesso ao controller ficou assim
`http://meudominio.com/mod/mod_upload`
`http://meudominio.com/mod/mod_config`
`http://meudominio.com/mod/mod_logo_upload`

Para evitar a indexação das paginas, e acabar aparecendo no google, basta somente "bloquear o diretorio /mod" no arquivo roobts.txt ? ou somente o login sera bastante ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se estas rotas tiverem autenticação, provavelmente usuários não autenticados são redirecionados devem visualizar a página de login, no caso um BOT também deve visualizar a página de login (pois em minha opinião os bots devem ver as páginas da mesma maneira que o usuário), se este for o caso você pode usar o código http 401 (Não autorizado):

- php 5.4+:

  ```
  if (false === $condicao_necessaria_para_acesso) {
      http_response_code(401);
      //View para login
  } else {
      //Condição normal, views, models, etc
  }
  ```
- php inferior ao 5.4:

  ```
  if (false === $condicao_necessaria_para_acesso) {
      header('X-PHP-Response-Code: 401', true, 401);
      //View para login
  } else {
      //Condição normal, views, models, etc
  }
  ```

Se a página não tiver autenticação, mas a rota for acessível por um endereço ou por um `user-agent` especifico, você pode usar o código http 403 (Proibido) com `exit;`, assim não precisa enviar uma página customizada, no caso o navegador quando não tem conteúdo geralmente mostra uma página de erro padrão dele e os buscadores não indexam está página.

- Use uma condição para informar o acesso:

  ```
  if (false === $condicao_necessaria_para_acesso) {
      http_response_code(403);
      exit;
  }
  ```
- php < 5.4:

  ```
  if (false === $condicao_necessaria_para_acesso) {
      header('X-PHP-Response-Code: 403', true, 403);
      exit;
  }
  ```